# One WCF Service to Rule them All? (SOAP w https, oData, JSON, POX, etc...)

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, odata

I've been playing around with WCF and I have managed to a WCF service to generate both SOAP, POX, and JSON formats pretty easily based on this example (I added the soap config).

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ashutosh.shukla1/3040/Default.aspx

And I see that if you add a timestamp field to your data base tables you can actually have a plain old WCF service work with Linq to SQL via this-

http://jonkruger.com/blog/2008/02/10/linq-to-sql-in-disconnectedn-tier-scenarios-saving-an-object/

I'm still a little confused about WCF vs WCF Data Services vs WCF Ria Services.  I guess my goal and my question is.

Is it possible to write one service with multiple endpoints that does it all...POX, JSON, Java client compatible SOAP 1.1 with https and user name/password protection, and OData secured with https possibly as well?  If so that sounds amazing, as I can create a self hosted uber data provider service that offers numerous ways clients can connect and use data.

Are we there yet?  If so what do I use (still confused on the differences)?

Comment: Looks like there is a fork in the road between SOAP and oDATA. At least from my initial passes it "looks" like you can use one service for both, but things start getting weird when you expose end point mex type stuff (JSON, POX, etc ) WebGet and WebPost methods will show up in the generated SOAP WSDL as valid SOAP calls (and interestingly they work).  I'm still exploring but ran into some cross domain pain the arse issues too when I put some WCF service in a ServiceHost. Oh well, any takers yet? I'll leave this up for a while. services.